# Gravity Forms - Untick a checkbox when a radio button is ticked (or vice versa)

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm building up a Gravity form and the client has the following scenario:

Item 1 - This is a checkbox on its own as it is an optional choice

Item 2 - This is a radio button (User chooses either this item or item 3)

Item 3 - This is a radio button (User chooses either this item or item 2)

When the user chooses Item 2 or Item 3, the below radio buttons will appear:

1. 1 Day
2. 2 Days
3. 3 Days
4. 3 Days + Item 1

Now the client would like that the user can optionally choose Item 1 and then one of the other items including the days that they would like to choose. However, if they choose '3 Days + Item 1' from Item 2 or Item 3, the checkbox of Item 1 gets unchecked so as not to incur a double selection or else an additional price since the '3 Days + Item 1' has a special price point.

Can this be done in some way using Gravity Forms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas...

1. Easiest and requiring no coding:  Don't bother trying to check or uncheck the box.  Just make two fields, one that has radio buttons 1,2,3 and another that has 1,2,4.  Make it so one of these fields appears when the item 2 or 3 are checked and item 1 is not checked, and make the second one conditionally appear when item 1 and either item 2 or three are checked.  make the second radio field (the one with option 4 in it) have its own price code for the combo deal.
2. Make a hidden field that adds a discount conditionally appear if the checkbox and 3 days are selected.  Add that discount field into your calculations.
3. (not my favorite, but it works)
   Separate the first part from the second part into separate pages, then use the pre_submission_filter (include all four filters mentioned on gf docs) to populate page two based on page 1 choices (can do that via rgpost).